# Remove everything that doesn't match

Tags: c#, regex, string

```
string line = "Rok rok irrelevant text irrelevant;text.irrelevant,text"; 
string NewLine = Regex.Replace(line, @"\b[rR]\w*", "");
```

Right now it replaces every word starting with r/R with a blank space, but I want to make everything a blank space EXCEPT words starting with r/R.

Comment: Try `\b(?![rR])\w+`, or even `\b(?![rR])\w+\W*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works. https://regex101.com/r/WxzUje/1/

Comment: @Omegand for future references you could refer to: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html (negative lookahead)

Comment: Ok it almost works, it doesn't match seperators(white space, dot, colon)

Comment: @Omegand Dots, colons, spaces are not word characters. That is why I  also suggested `\W*`. You may also try `\W*\b(?![rR])\w+\W*` and replace with  a space, and `.Trim()` the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

It seems all you want is to *extract* words starting with `r` or `R` and join them with a space. In this case, use a mere `\b[rR]\w*` regex and the following code:

```
var result = string.Join(" ", Regex.Matches(line, @"\b[rR]\w*").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value));
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/0q6XxC).

**Original answer**

You may use a [*negative lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) after a word boundary:

```
\b(?![rR])\w+
  ^^^^^^^^
```

Note that the `+` quantifier is better here since you want to remove at least 1 char found.

Or, in case you also want to remove all non-word chars after the found word, use

```
\b(?![rR])\w+\W*
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/WxzUje/1/) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/WxzUje/2).

If you want to remove any non-word chars *before and after* a qualifying word, use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(line, @"\W*\b(?![rR])\w+\W*", " ").Trim();
```

It will remove all non-word chars before a word not starting with `r` and `R` and after it.

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?![rR])` - a negative lookahead that will fail the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is `r` or `R`
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\W*` - 0+ non-word chars.

Comment: The 2nd one does what I want , but it matches everything except the word I need Plus any seperators(colon,dot,whitespace) that are after it. I need it only to match the word alone without them.

Comment: @Omegand You have `Rok rok irrelevant text irrelevant;text.irrelevant,text`. What do you want to change it to?

Comment: I'll change the string a bit to "Rok rok Rok. Rok( Rok) irrelevant text irrelevant;text.irrelevant,text" I want it turned into "Rok rok Rok Rok Rok". In your example the regex pattern would catch Rok. and Rok( , but I want the clean word + whitespace.

Comment: @Omegand You mean you want to replace also all the non-word char sequences? Like `Regex.Replace(line, @"\W*\b(?![rR])\w+\W*|\W+", " ").Trim()`? See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/z2Mr9S). Wait, you are much better off with a matching approach then. I added a new solution at the top of the answer.

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted. I didn't think this through enough and didn't expect it to be this difficult my bad